# passing multiple variables to codeigniter controller from view with jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a view, that using jquery posts some information to the controller. the controller then runs some logic using the post information and returns the result to a div in my view.

my view syntax is:

```
 $.post("get_link_load_options", { varlatitude: latitude, varlongitude: longitude }).done(function(data) { 
      $('#results').html(result);    
  });
```

My Controller syntax is:

```
function get_link_load_options(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $data['result'] = $this->Sales_model->get_link_load_options($q);
        $this->load->view('sales\link_order_options',$data);
    }
}
```

Currently, with this syntax the div is populated with the value of the variable latitude and is duplicated.

How can I show the contents of the view `link_order_options` and also, how do I access each variable in the controller so I can perform logic with it. currently $q fetched the data variable/array.

how do I store each of latitude and longitude as a PHP variable in my controller?

Thanks as always.

Comment: You can use Codeigniter's `Input Class` to retrieve the post data. Check answer below.

Comment: You're not posting any `data` to the controller, only `varlatitude` and `varlongtitude`. Which means in the controller you'll find them by accessing `$_POST['varlatitude']` and `$_POST['varlongtitude']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demonstration

Controller

```
function get_link_load_options()
{
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        $varlatitude    =   $this->inpput->post('varlatitude');
        $varlongitude   =   $this->inpput->post('varlongitude');

        $data['result'] =   $this->Sales_model->get_link_load_options($varlatitude , $varlongitude);
        $this->load->view('sales\link_order_options',$data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function get_link_load_options($latitude , $longitude)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

Ajax

```
var latitude    =   $('#latitude_input_field_id').val();
var longitude   =   $('#longitude_input_field_id').val();

$.post("get_link_load_options", { varlatitude: latitude, varlongitude: longitude }).done(function(data) { 
  $('#results').html(data);    
});
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="latitude_input_field_id" />  
<input type="text" id="longitude_input_field_id" /> 

<div id="results">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Codeigniter's [Input Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) to retrieve the post data.

This might help you:

```
if($this->input->post()) {
    $varlatitude = $this->input->post('varlatitude'); 
    $varlongitude = $this->input->post('varlongitude');
}
```